# Shimano spd pedal clicking on downstroke on left side

Tags: shimano, clicking

I got a pair of shimano spd pedals less than a month ago and installed them on my bike (currently set up on an indoor trainer) and started to notice a click recently on the downstroke as I come over the top, only on the left pedal. I checked and it is not catching any part of the bike and when I put my flat pedals back on there is no click so I know it's coming from the pedal (still clicks if I just use regular shoes with the shiramo pedal). Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  You're talking about the classic SPD (mountain bike-ish) pedals and not the SPD-SL road pedals, correct?  Is it possible that the spring doesn't have enough tension to hold the cleat fully engaged under load?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. It's the spd sl road pedal that clicks. I rode without the bike shoe and just used my regular shoes and the clicking was still there so it shouldn't have anything to do with the cleat

Comment: Does the pedal wobble on its axle at all, or is it noticeably looser than the opposite one? Or compare to other pedals you have. A stiff pedal can also click. Also do check your cranks are fully tightened, and the pedals into the cranks, while you're at it. I know it didn't click with flats, but these noises can be intermittent or affected by the way you press on different pedals.

Comment: It doesnt wobble and im not sure how tight it is supposed to be but i took it off and re-installed it last night and its about a half turn past hand tight. i havent taken the right pedal (the one that doesnt click) off or loosen it up to compare it to. there is no side to side movement in the crank

Comment: Does the pedal spin smoothly without any bearing play? Can you reproduce the clicking sound with your hands? Are you sure it’s not the saddle or any other component? As for installation torque: Manufacturers usually say >30Nm, which is a lot (for comparison, the clamping bolts on your stem are usually 4Nm or 5Nm). You basically can’t use too much force unless you have a really long wrench. Make sure there is grease or at least oil on the threads. And don’t forget that the left pedal has a left hand thread.

Comment: The pedal that clicks spins more freely it seems than the one that doesn't. I was able to make it click this morning with my hands and I can feel it click as it turned it. I did not grease the pedals when I installed them. What is the recommended type of grease for pedals?

Comment: That's everyone for the help! I bought and applied some grease to the threads and the clicking went away